# How to make Liveview mode in Canon 450D stop simulating exposure?

Tags: canon, exposure, live-view, canon-450d

On the Canon EOS 450D (Rebel XSi) camera, Liveview mode always shows the true exposure of the image. If exposure is set too dark (fast shutter and closed aperture), Liveview shows a darker image. If exposure is set too bright (slow shutter and open aperture), Liveview shows a brighter image.

However some cameras do have an option to select whether the camera should always show a truly exposed image or, otherwise, always how a normally exposed image.

How do I switch my 450D to the second behavior?

Comment: This may be possible using Magic Lantern firmware, but I don't have enough experience with it to be able to include this in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [manual](http://files.canon-europe.com/files/soft31340/Manual/CUG_EOS450D_EN_Flat.pdf) (specifically, page 96) this is not possible with the Canon EOS 450D. However on page 97 there is this information:

> If the [Custom Functions (C.Fn)]’s menu [Auto Lighting Optimizer]
>   (p.156) is set to [0: Enable], a darkly-exposed (set with exposure
>   compensation) image may be displayed brighter.

This might help where your exposure settings result in a too-dark image on the screen, though from the description only in certain conditions (i.e. when using exposure compensation). I don't know whether it will help with overexposed images.